# How to remove a None type from a string

Tags: python, web-scraping, non-type

I am scraping a webpage using this code

```
import requests
import bs4

res=requests.get(URL)
res.text
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
lis=[]
for k in soup.find_all('a'):
    Fin=(k.get('href'))
    print(Fin)
lis=Fin.split()
```

'Fin' contain a string like that:

```
https://video-it.eurosport.com
https://help.eurosport.com/hc/it
#
#
https://it.eurosport.com
None
https://help.eurosport.com/hc/it
```

But the program return the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

As checked with the function 'type' Fin it's a string but i can't do anything with it because it's a 'Non-type' object.

I don't know how to solve the problem even because the 'None-type' is in the string indeed of a list so i can't use the function filter...
*So my question is how to remove the 'None-type'?*

Comment: I don't think it's very useful to confirm that `Fin` is a string, because you're not calling `split` on Fin, you're calling it on `table`. Where is `table` first defined in your code?

Comment: Bad name aside, why do you initialize `list` to the empty list, but then ignore that list and replace it with the result of `table.split()` (whatever `table` is)?

Comment: I badly reported the code, now it's correct. I'm Sorry

Comment: I don't think `Fin` is a string with the value `"None"`, rather it is a variable set to None (python's null) with type = `<class 'NoneType'>`. You can try a truthy check of Fin before trying to split it.

Answer (score 1):

you can filter an remove None from Fin:

```
arr = list(filter(None, Fin))

arr.split()
```

at least for me it looks cleaner than list Comprehension:

```
arr = [x for x in Fin if x != None]

arr.split()
```

Comment: It returns the same error. Thanks for your time by the way

Comment: if Fin is None, that means of type None then it can't be splited of course! try print(type(Fin)). maybe Fin is None and the k.get(url) function is not working as it supposed to be